# libmtp on mac os can not connect using mtp-connect

Tags: macos, libusb, mtp

i'm trying to get files in mtp device using command line interface from libmtp.
When i hit mtp-connect, the console showed:

```
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
libusb_detach_kernel_driver() failed, continuing anyway...: Invalid argument
```

Thank you and appreciate any feedback.

- Note:
  libmtp version: 1.1.20
  mac os version: 12.6.6